# How to keep a user logged in a flutter app using JWT?

Tags: flutter, jwt

I am using JWT for authentication purposes for my flutter app. I can successfully log in and logout but the problem is when the token expires. Should I store the user's username/password in secure storage and then get a new token?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference "local database", to store JWT token or ( get new token when token expires and when your app launches )